# Pdf produced using FlyingSaucer/iTExt5 is blank

Tags: pdf, itext, pdf-generation, flying-saucer

I am trying to generate a PDF from a html string and am getting a response but the document is not displayed in the PDF viewer. I appears like I am missing something and the response is a corrupt PDF. Would highly appreciate it if I could get any suggestions.

Have included the following in my pom.xml

```
    <!-- dependencies for saving as PDF -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
  <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
  <version>5.5.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
  <artifactId>flying-saucer-core</artifactId>
  <version>9.1.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
  <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf-itext5</artifactId>
  <version>9.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

My endpoint is a controller and the code looks as below:

```
    @POST
@Produces({"application/pdf"})
@Path("/renderPDF")
public void renderPDF(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response) throws WebAppException {
    try {
        String  = "<html><body>some content</body></html>";
        RenderPDF.createPDF(response, sb);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("renderPDF", e);
    }
}
```

createPDF is defined below:

```
public class RenderPDF {
public static void createPDF(HttpServletResponse response, String html)
        throws IOException, DocumentException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
    try {
        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
        renderer.layout();

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        renderer.createPDF(baos);

        // setting some response headers
        response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control",
                "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
        // setting the content type
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        // the contentlength
        response.setContentLength(baos.size());

        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        baos.writeTo(os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: The issue was in my angular http interceptor; the response type needed to be set to arrayBuffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in my angular http interceptor; the response type needed to be set to arrayBuffer.